# How to inject dependency using Factory Pattern in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this situation

```
abstract class Importer {

    const NW = 1;

    public static function getInstance($type)
    {
        switch($type)
        {
            case(self::NW):
            return new NWImporter();
            break;
        }
    }

    protected function saveObject(myObject $myObject)
    {
        //here I need to use doctrine to save on mongodb
    }

    abstract function import($nid);
}
```

and

```
class NWImporter extends Importer
{
    public function import($nid)
    {
        //do some staff, create myObject and call the parent method to save it
        parent::saveObject($myObject);
    }
}
```

and I want to use them like this

```
 $importer = Importer::getInstance(Importer::NW);
 $importer->import($nid);
```

my question is: how to inject doctrine to be used in saveObject method?

thanks

Comment: Declare your class as service passing argument `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager`

Comment: can you provide an example? I tried already with services

Comment: see below @elkorchianas anwser :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your importer as a symfony service :

```
services:
    test.common.exporter:
        # put the name space of your class
        class:  Test\CommonBundle\NWImporter 
        arguments: [ "@doctrine" ]
```

then in NWImporter define a constructor with a parameter that will have the doctrine instance

```
public function __construct($doctrine)
  {
    $this->doctrine= $doctrine;
  }
```

with this solution you can avoid using a factory method as symfony does it for you but if you wanna to keep it, When you call `$importer = Importer::getInstance(Importer::NW);` from your controller you can inject the doctrine argument in your factory method :

```
abstract class Importer {

    const NW = 1;

    public static function getInstance($type, $doctrine)
    {
        switch($type)
        {
            case(self::NW):
            return new NWImporter($doctrine);
            break;
        }
    }

    protected function saveObject(myObject $myObject)
    {
        //here I need to use doctrine to save on mongodb
    }

    abstract function import($nid);
}
```

then in your controller you should to do something like that :

```
 $doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
 $importer = Importer::getInstance(Importer::NW, $doctrine);
 $importer->import($nid);
```

Comment: I tried already but I got an error because Importer has "return new NWImporter();" expecting I pass a parameter...

Comment: You are calling NWImporter::getInstance() from where is it from your controller ?

Comment: yes I want to call it from a controller, and, I can't inject to Importer because NWImporter extends importer, and once again the construct expects a parameter...

Comment: they both work but if I want to use the factory pattern (and I want to use it because I need several different importers) I must pass doctrine to the factory. Now I don't know if this is a good practice but it works so thanks you.

Comment: you welcome :), I think it's still a good practice because the main purpose of the factory pattern is to instantiate and configure dependencies of a service which is the case